# How to change IIS Express site name in Visual studio project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Hi I have two solution file
one is called WWSearch and the other WWSearchDev.
WWSearchDev was copied from WWSearch.
both solution has ASP.net web form project.

I searched everywhere in WWSearchDev for the word "WWSearch" and it has no reference to "WWSearch".
But when I run the code IIS express still says the site name is WWSearch

The problem is the path of WWSearchDev should be C:\VSS\WWSearchDev. *see screenshot.

I tried adding a new site in  IIE express application config file in 
C:\Users\%username%\Documents\IISExpress\config\Applicationhost.config. 
but It still not working

please  help.. Thank you

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9ubfxAa.png]

This is the applicationhost.config for IIS

```
<sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="WWSearch" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\VSS\WWSearch" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49454:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="WWSearchDev" id="3">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\VSS\WWSearchDev" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52184:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>         
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 ) find YourWebSite.sln file

2) open with notepad

3) in 5 or 6th line, find you website name, rename it

4) save&exit

Comment: for find *.sln, click on solution in visual studio and see path address in properties_______for rename solution, right-click, then rename.

Comment: Before changing the name of the project and the name in the solution, clean the solution to get rid of the existing DLLs.

Comment: This is the very correct answer! And you only have to change this... Project("{Some_GUID}") = "PROJECT_NAME_change_this", "PROJECT_NAME_no_need_to_change.csproj", "{Some_GUID}"

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem for **HTTPS** and Visual Studio 2015.

The IIS Express configuration file :

"C:\Users{username}\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" 
**didn´t** have the reference for my site.

I found the reference **inside the solution** directory in a hide directory

"{Solution}\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"

I removed the entry for the old copy site, closed and reopen the project and everything was right.

Comment: I faced same issue in VS 2022 and resolved with idea from this solution. I closed the project from Visual Studio. Then enabled showing hiden files from directory. Finally deleted the .vs folder. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1InpwsUqI71NhgUyCAi55W_lJuaUzUH_9/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 6):

1. Open with sublime text3
2. Find folder .vs > config > applicationhost.config
3. Searh old Site name & Change new name
4. save

Comment: I found my applicationhost.config in: C:\Projects\ProjectFolder\.vs\ProjectFolder\config

Comment: For anyone else that didn't know what "Sublime Text3" is ---- it is a text editor. You can use any text editor you like, including Notepad.